# raise ValueError("Selector needs either text or root argument")

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I used scrapy+splash to make splash click on the button on the following website: https://www.daraz.pk/smartphones/ and then return the html of the newly rendered page.

The code is as follow

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class DarazsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'darazs'
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 60000,
        'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE': 0,
        'DOWNLOAD_WARNSIZE': 0
    }
    script = '''
function main(splash, args)
assert(splash:go(args.url))
assert(splash:wait(0.5))
treat=require('treat')
result = {}
for i=2,68,1
    do
        assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector(".ant-pagination-next > a").click()'))
        assert(splash:wait(5.0))
        result[i]=splash:html()


    end  
return treat.as_array(result)
end
    '''

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.daraz.pk/smartphones/'
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait': 0.5})
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse_other_pages, endpoint='execute',
                            args={'wait': 0.5, 'lua_source': self.script, 'timeout': 3600}, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        for phone in response.xpath('//div[@class="c2prKC"]'):
            yield {
                'Name': phone.xpath('.//div[@class="c16H9d"]/a/text()').extract(),
                'Price': phone.xpath('.//span[@class="c13VH6"]/text()').extract(),
                'old_price': phone.xpath('.//del[@class="c13VH6"]/text()').extract(),

            }

    def parse_other_pages(self, response):
        for page in response.data:
            sel = Selector(text=page, type=None, root=None)
            for phone in sel.xpath('//div[@class="c2prKC"]'):
                yield {
                    'Name': phone.xpath('.//div[@class="c16H9d"]/a/text()').extract(),
                    'Price': phone.xpath('.//span[@class="c13VH6"]/text()').extract(),
                    'old_price': phone.xpath('.//del[@class="c13VH6"]/text()').extract(),

                }
```

It runs the first parse function correctly and scrpes data from the first page but it doesn't scrape other pages and it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy_splash/middleware.py", line 156, in process_spider_output
    for el in result:
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/daraz/daraz/spiders/darazs.py", line 50, in parse_other_pages
    sel = Selector(text=page, type=None, root=None)
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 84, in __init__
    super(Selector, self).__init__(text=text, type=st, root=root, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 195, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Selector needs either text or root argument")
ValueError: Selector needs either text or root argument
```

I think there is an error in lua script. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you inspected the contents of `page` in `File "/home/ibtsam/PycharmProjects/dsf/daraz/daraz/spiders/darazs.py", line 50, in parse_other_pages`? The exception seems caused by it being `None`.